# how to use colspan in <ul> <li> while creating a table by using <div>

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a table using `<ul>` `<li>` `<div>`. i am facing problem for using colspan.
i am trying to create a dynamic pricing table but facing problem while colspan the table while design it with help of `<ul>` `<li>` `<div>`.
I am also using if else condition for fetching values from database

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 2):

Colspan is only specified for td tags so you can't use it with other elements. It sounds like you are creating a "real" table here, meant to show data and to compare it. In this case it is semantically right to use the table element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "columns" css attribute on the ul:
ul.columns: 2;